# Odd Results in Pivot Table based on Power Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have been receiving odd results when updating a Pivot Table based on two tables combined using PowerPivot.

Nearly all of it updates as expected, but for a few entries, corresponding data doesn't update as expected for all values.

Below is a screenshot of various scenarios.  The first two columns are from the pivot table and the third column is the data.

The third column is set to only allow "Team 1", "Team 2", "Both", and a few others.

For the third and fourth row ("Customer list", "Project 4") when I try to set it to "Team 1" it updates as "Both" (Scenario 1).

There's a subtle formatting difference in Scenario 2 & 3 when I *actually* set the value to Both (note the line moving that appears to delineate true "Both" entries vs. unexpected "Both" results.

In Scenario 4, I can set it to Team 2 and it works as expected.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example of images.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the tabs with the data and recreating the PowerPivot model & Pivot table.  Seems to be working properly now.  There have been issues with crashes / not properly saving so perhaps there was some sort of corruption.